# compare columns over two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that look like:

```
import pandas as pd

f1 = {'entity':['X','Y','Z'],'instrument':['A','B','C'],'Function':['Rates','FX','Rates'],'amt':[1,2,3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=f1)

f2 = {'entity':['X','Y','Z'],'instrument':['A','B','C'],'Depot':['A','A','B'],'amt':[1,2,3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=f2)
```

When I try to iterate over the columns of the two dataframes, I get an error. Any ideas why ?

```
common_cols=['entity','instrument']
common_cols_iter=iter(common_cols)

for index1,row1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index2,row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row1[next(common_cols_iter)]==row2[next(common_cols_iter)]:
            print("common")
        else:
            print("not")
```

I am trying to achieve:

```
for index1,row1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index2,row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if (row1['entity']==row2['entity'] and row1['instrument']==row2['instrument']):
            print("common")
        else:
            print("not")
```

Comment: Do you want this to compare every row to every row on purpose?  Or are you trying to compare row1 with row 1, row2 with row 2, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you iterate over columns using a for?

```
common_cols=['entity','instrument']
common_cols_iter=iter(common_cols)

def check_cond(row1,row2):
    for col in common_cols:
        if row1[col] != row2[col]:
            return False
    return True

for index1,row1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index2,row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if check_cond(row1,row2):
            print("common")
        else:
            print("not")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
next(common_cols_iter)
```

will only work two times in your code, after that it'll say stop iteration.